# ID tag is not auto incrementing the numbers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am learning python and trying to replicate what online tutorials do. I am trying to create a python desktop app where data is store in Postgresql. code is added below,

```
 `cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title text, author text, year integer, isbn integer)")`
```

problem is with (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY), when i execute the code its showing none in place of 1st index. i want to show numbers. 
please help

this is for Python 3.7.3, psycopg2==2.8.3,

```
def connect():
conn=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
cur=conn.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,                    
title text, author text, year integer, isbn integer)")
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

the result I am expecting is auto increment of numbers in 1st index where as presently it shows NONE.
below is the present and expected result again.
none title auther year isbn
01 title auther year isbn

Comment: Show the code responsible for inserting data to your database

Comment: Since I am learning it, I am inserting the data manually. here is the complete backend code.

Comment: here is the link for back end code[trinket.io/python/629a4b47e9?showInstructions=true], here is the link for front end code [trinket.io/python/b5704774b8]

Answer (score 1):

Trying to use a Cursor execute will not work for a CREATE statement and hence the NONE. See below for an example.

## Re Indexes :-

There will be no specific index as `column_name INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` is special in that it defines the column as an alias of the rowid column which is a special intrinsic index using the underlying B-tree storage engine.

When a row is inserted then if no value is specified for the column (e.g. `INSERT INTO book (title,author, year, isbn) VALUES ('book1','The Author','1999','1234567890')` then **id** will be 1 and typically (but not certainly) the next row inserted will have an **id** of 2 and so on.

If after adding some rows you use `SELECT * FROM book`, then the rows will be ordered according to the **id** as no other index is specified/used.

Perhaps have a look at [Rowid Tables](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html).

## Example

Perhaps consider the following example :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS book;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title text, author text, year integer, isbn integer);
INSERT INTO book (title,author, year, isbn) VALUES 
    ('book1','The Author','1999','1234567890'),
    ('book2','Author 2','1899','2234567890'),
    ('book3','Author 3','1799','3234567890')
;
INSERT INTO book VALUES (100,'book10','Author 10','1999','4234567890'); --<<<<<<<<<< specific ID
INSERT INTO book (title,author, year, isbn) VALUES 
    ('book11','Author 11','1999','1234567890'),
    ('book12','Author 12','1899','2234567890'),
    ('book13','Author 13','1799','3234567890')
;
INSERT INTO book VALUES (10,'book10','Author 10','1999','4234567890'); --<<<<<<<<<< specific ID
SELECT * FROM book;
```

This :-

1. **DROP**s the book table (to make it easily re-runable)
2. **CREATE**s the book table.
3. **INSERT**s 3 books with the **id** not specified (typpical)
4. **INSERT**s a fourth book but with a specific **id** of 100
5. **INSERT**s another 3 books (not that these will be 101-103 as 100 is the highest id before the inserts)
6. **INSERT**s a last row BUT with a specific **id** of 10.
7. **SELECT**s all rows with all columns from the book table ordered, as no **ORDER BY** has been specified, according to the hidden index based upon the **id**. NOTE although id 10 was the last inserted it is the 4th row.

## Result

[image]

## In Python :-

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("books.db")
conn.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS book")
conn.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,title text, author text, year integer, isbn integer)")
conn.execute("INSERT INTO book (title,author, year, isbn) "
             "VALUES('book1','The Author','1999','1234567890'), "
             "('book2','Author 2','1899','2234567890'), "
             "('book3','Author 3','1799','3234567890');")
conn.execute("INSERT INTO book VALUES (100,'book10','Author 10','1999','4234567890'); --<<<<<<<<<< specific ID")
conn.execute("INSERT INTO book (title,author, year, isbn) VALUES ('book11','Author 11','1999','1234567890'),('book12','Author 12','1899','2234567890'),('book13','Author 13','1799','3234567890');")
conn.execute("INSERT INTO book VALUES (10,'book10','Author 10','1999','4234567890'); --<<<<<<<<<< specific ID")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM book") 
for each in cur:
    print("{0:<20} {1:<20} {2:<20} {3:<20} {4:<20}".format(each[0],each[1],each[2],each[3],each[4]))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

The results in :-

```
1                    book1                The Author           1999                 1234567890          
2                    book2                Author 2             1899                 2234567890          
3                    book3                Author 3             1799                 3234567890          
10                   book10               Author 10            1999                 4234567890          
100                  book10               Author 10            1999                 4234567890          
101                  book11               Author 11            1999                 1234567890          
102                  book12               Author 12            1899                 2234567890          
103                  book13               Author 13            1799                 3234567890
```

Comment: Thanks. this is the exact result i wanted but I am unable to do so from my current codes.

Comment: @NazeemNajmu compare the code you are basically trying to return data (result set/ cursor) from a CREATE TABLE .statement. Which will return nothing and hence the NONE. For a cursor execute you need a SELECT statement. You should be able to copy the code above or parts thereof (perhaps you just need the last 6 lines if you already have data).

Comment: here is the link for back end code[https://trinket.io/python/629a4b47e9?showInstructions=true], here is the link for front end code [https://trinket.io/python/b5704774b8]

Answer (score 1):

because you say *I am inserting the data manually* then instead of

```
def connect():
conn=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
cur=conn.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,                    
title text, author text, year integer, isbn integer)")
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Try to use

```
def connect():
conn=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
cur=conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM books")
for row in cur:
    print(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4])
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```